# Nexentastor 4: lost connection to storage and web interface

Tags: nexenta

I have a server that runs nexentastor version 4. I use web interface to manage it. The server has been working on production environment for about two years with no issues until last week - where I could no connect to the web interface, and I lost connection to the storage as well. When I tried to login to the console using root, it took long time to authenticate - and then it displayed the following lines:

```
login as: root
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Initializing recovery session. The operation may take up to 6 minutes.
Remains: 330 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 300 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 270 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 240 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 210 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 180 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 150 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 120 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 90 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 60 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 30 seconds. Please stand by...
Remains: 0 seconds. Please stand by...

                          * * *
                      SYSTEM NOTICE

     Failed to initialize NMC:
     The name com.nexenta.nms was not provided by any .service files

     Suggested possible recovery actions:
        - Reboot into a known working system checkpoint
        - Run 'svcadm clear nms'; then try to re-login
        - Run 'svcadm enable -rs nms' to enable nms daemon and then try to re-login
     Suggested troubleshooting actions:
        - Run 'svcs -vx' and collect output for further analysis
        - Run 'dmesg' and look for error messages
        - View "/var/log/nms.log" for error messages
        - View "/var/svc/log/application-nms:default.log" for error messages

Entering UNIX shell. Type 'exit' to go back to NMC login...
```

I ran the commands in the suggested possible recovery and troubleshooting actions, but I was not able to resolve the issue. Below are some log data from the log files.

```
/var/log/nms.log
================
Aug  9 17:47:46 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Starting...
Aug  9 17:47:46 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing devices...
Aug  9 17:47:51 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Warning: format timeout: Command timed out
Aug  9 17:47:56 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Warning: rmformat timeout: Command timed out
Aug  9 17:47:56 myhost nms[674]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing time...
Aug  9 17:47:58 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing LUNs...
Aug  9 17:48:24 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing datasets ...
Aug  9 17:48:24 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Loading plugins ...
Aug  9 17:48:26 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] scsitarget: importing Volumes
Aug  9 17:48:26 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] scsitarget: comstar plugin loaded
Aug  9 17:48:26 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Plugin: nms-comstar, v40-0-20, (COMSTAR Target extension)
Aug  9 17:48:26 myhost nms[543]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Starting IPC listener...
Aug  9 17:48:26 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.1) Group sync OK
Aug  9 17:48:26 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.1) Delayed server "pooling" (initial count = 2)
Aug  9 17:48:27 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.1) Nexenta Management Server is ready (881)
Aug  9 17:48:58 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Starting...
Aug  9 17:48:59 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Syncing LUNs...
Aug  9 17:49:01 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Syncing datasets ...
Aug  9 17:49:01 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Loading plugins ...
Aug  9 17:49:03 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) scsitarget: importing Volumes
Aug  9 17:49:03 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) scsitarget: comstar plugin loaded
Aug  9 17:49:03 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Plugin: nms-comstar, v40-0-20, (COMSTAR Target extension)
Aug  9 17:49:03 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Starting IPC listener...
Aug  9 17:49:03 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Nexenta Management Server is ready (1:967)
Aug  9 17:49:11 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Starting...
Aug  9 17:49:12 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Syncing LUNs...
Aug  9 17:49:13 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Syncing datasets ...
Aug  9 17:49:14 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Loading plugins ...
Aug  9 17:49:15 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) scsitarget: importing Volumes
Aug  9 17:49:15 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) scsitarget: comstar plugin loaded
Aug  9 17:49:15 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Plugin: nms-comstar, v40-0-20, (COMSTAR Target extension)
Aug  9 17:49:15 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Starting IPC listener...
Aug  9 17:49:15 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Nexenta Management Server is ready (2:1213)
Aug  9 17:49:22 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.6) Server "pooling": 2 management servers in a pool, in addition to the main NMS
Aug 10 11:29:41 myhost hosts-check[1860]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:29:52 myhost volume-check[2192]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:30:05 myhost ses-check[1498]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:30:19 myhost nfs-collector[1380]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:34:41 myhost hosts-check[1860]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:34:52 myhost volume-check[2192]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:35:05 myhost ses-check[1498]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:35:19 myhost nfs-collector[1380]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 11:39:41 myhost hosts-check[1860]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 11:39:52 myhost volume-check[2192]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 11:40:06 myhost ses-check[1498]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 11:40:19 myhost nfs-collector[1380]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 13:34:37 myhost nms[967]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:1.1) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 881
Aug 10 13:34:37 myhost nms[1213]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:1.124) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 881
Aug 10 13:34:38 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 957
Aug 10 13:34:38 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 1202
Aug 10 13:34:38 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 1213
Aug 10 13:34:38 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 2212
Aug 10 13:34:43 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 2398
Aug 10 13:34:48 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 3314
Aug 10 13:34:53 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 3488
Aug 10 13:34:58 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 3521
Aug 10 13:35:03 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 3609
Aug 10 13:35:03 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) All child processes terminated now (9)
Aug 10 13:35:03 myhost nms[881]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.762) Closing server log...
Aug 10 13:47:20 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Starting...
Aug 10 13:47:20 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing devices...
Aug 10 13:47:25 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Warning: format timeout: Command timed out
Aug 10 13:47:30 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Warning: rmformat timeout: Command timed out
Aug 10 13:47:30 myhost nms[3751]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing time...
Aug 10 13:47:31 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing LUNs...
Aug 10 13:47:58 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Syncing datasets ...
Aug 10 13:47:58 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Loading plugins ...
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] scsitarget: importing Volumes
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] scsitarget: comstar plugin loaded
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Plugin: nms-comstar, v40-0-20, (COMSTAR Target extension)
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3723]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Starting IPC listener...
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.772) Group sync OK
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.772) Delayed server "pooling" (initial count = 2)
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.772) Warning: NMV maintenance state cleared...
Aug 10 13:48:00 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.772) Nexenta Management Server is ready (3968)
Aug 10 13:48:32 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Starting...
Aug 10 13:48:33 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Syncing LUNs...
Aug 10 13:48:35 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Syncing datasets ...
Aug 10 13:48:35 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Warning: Database file /var/lib/nza/report.db corrupted and saved as: /var/lib/nza/report.db.corrupted_2017_Aug_10_13_48_35
Aug 10 13:48:35 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Warning: Database will be recreated
Aug 10 13:48:36 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Loading plugins ...
Aug 10 13:48:36 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) scsitarget: importing Volumes
Aug 10 13:48:36 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) scsitarget: comstar plugin loaded
Aug 10 13:48:36 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Plugin: nms-comstar, v40-0-20, (COMSTAR Target extension)
Aug 10 13:48:36 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Starting IPC listener...
Aug 10 13:48:37 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:) Nexenta Management Server is ready (1:4068)
Aug 10 13:48:45 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Starting...
Aug 10 13:48:46 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Syncing LUNs...
Aug 10 13:48:47 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Syncing datasets ...
Aug 10 13:48:48 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Loading plugins ...
Aug 10 13:48:49 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) scsitarget: importing Volumes
Aug 10 13:48:49 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) scsitarget: comstar plugin loaded
Aug 10 13:48:49 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Plugin: nms-comstar, v40-0-20, (COMSTAR Target extension)
Aug 10 13:48:49 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Starting IPC listener...
Aug 10 13:48:49 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:) Nexenta Management Server is ready (2:4364)
Aug 10 13:48:56 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.779) Server "pooling": 2 management servers in a pool, in addition to the main NMS
Aug 10 13:58:40 myhost nfs-collector[4304]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 13:58:44 myhost hosts-check[4342]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 13:58:55 myhost volume-check[4051]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 13:59:31 myhost ses-check[3949]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 14:03:40 myhost nfs-collector[4304]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 14:03:44 myhost hosts-check[4342]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 14:03:55 myhost volume-check[4051]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 14:04:31 myhost ses-check[3949]: [ID 702911 local0.info] Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Aug 10 14:08:40 myhost nfs-collector[4304]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 14:08:44 myhost hosts-check[4342]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 14:08:55 myhost volume-check[4051]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 14:09:31 myhost ses-check[3949]: [ID 702911 local0.info] The exception (org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.) can be ignored..
Aug 10 15:27:19 myhost nms[4068]: [ID 702911 local0.info]   (1:1.2) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 3968
Aug 10 15:27:19 myhost nms[4364]: [ID 702911 local0.info]    (2:1.2) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 3968
Aug 10 15:27:20 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 4058
Aug 10 15:27:20 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 4353
Aug 10 15:27:20 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 4364
Aug 10 15:27:20 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 4885
Aug 10 15:27:25 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 5050
Aug 10 15:27:30 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 5209
Aug 10 15:27:35 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Sending signal 'TERM' to contract process member PID 5316
Aug 10 15:27:35 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) All child processes terminated now (7)
Aug 10 15:27:35 myhost nms[3968]: [ID 702911 local0.info] (:1.790) Closing server log...



/var/svc/log/application-nms:default.log
========================================
[ Aug  9 16:12:33 Enabled. ]
[ Aug  9 16:12:58 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/nms -d"). ]
[ Aug  9 16:13:51 Method "start" exited with status 0. ]
[ Aug  9 16:41:56 Stopping because service disabled. ]
[ Aug  9 16:41:56 Executing stop method ("/lib/svc/method/nms stop"). ]
Stopping NMS daemon (1:1208) ...
NMS daemon (1:1208) stopped (terminated)
Stopping NMS daemon (1107) ...
[ Aug  9 16:42:23 Method "stop" exited with status 0. ]
[ Aug  9 16:47:45 Enabled. ]
[ Aug  9 16:48:01 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/nms -d"). ]
[ Aug  9 17:48:26 Method "start" exited with status 0. ]
[ Aug 10 13:34:36 Stopping because service restarting. ]
[ Aug 10 13:34:36 Executing stop method ("/lib/svc/method/nms stop"). ]
Stopping NMS daemon (1:967) ...
NMS daemon (1:967) stopped (terminated)
Stopping NMS daemon (881) ...
NMS daemon (881) stopped (terminated)
[ Aug 10 13:38:19 Method "stop" exited with status 0. ]
[ Aug 10 13:38:36 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 80. ]
[ Aug 10 13:38:37 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 80. ]
[ Aug 10 13:38:38 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 80. ]
...
...
...
[ Aug 10 13:46:55 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 80. ]
[ Aug 10 13:46:56 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 80. ]
[ Aug 10 13:46:57 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 80. ]
[ Aug 10 13:47:18 Leaving maintenance because clear requested. ]
[ Aug 10 13:47:18 Enabled. ]
[ Aug 10 13:47:18 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/nms -d"). ]
[ Aug 10 13:48:00 Method "start" exited with status 0. ]
[ Aug 10 15:27:18 Stopping because service restarting. ]
[ Aug 10 15:27:18 Executing stop method ("/lib/svc/method/nms stop"). ]
Stopping NMS daemon (1:4068) ...
NMS daemon (1:4068) stopped (terminated)
Stopping NMS daemon (3968) ...
NMS daemon (3968) stopped (terminated)
[ Aug 10 15:31:00 Method "stop" exited with status 0. ]
[ Aug 10 15:31:19 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 128. ]
[ Aug 10 15:31:20 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 128. ]
[ Aug 10 15:31:21 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 128. ]
[ Aug 10 15:31:22 Method or service exit timed out.  Killing contract 128. ]
...
...
...
```

I hope someone can assist me with resolving this issue.

Here is the output of df:

```
root@myhost:~# df
/                  (syspool/rootfs-nmu-000):819438476 blocks 819438476 files
/devices           (/devices          ):       0 blocks        0 files
/dev               (/dev              ):       0 blocks        0 files
/system/contract   (ctfs              ):       0 blocks 2147483598 files
/proc              (proc              ):       0 blocks    29922 files
/etc/mnttab        (mnttab            ):       0 blocks        0 files
/etc/svc/volatile  (swap              ):224971408 blocks 18910464 files
/system/object     (objfs             ):       0 blocks 2147483412 files
/etc/dfs/sharetab  (sharefs           ):       0 blocks 2147483646 files
/lib/libc.so.1     (/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1):819438476 blocks 819438476 files
/dev/fd            (fd                ):       0 blocks        0 files
/tmp               (swap              ):224971408 blocks 18910464 files
/var/run           (swap              ):224971408 blocks 18910464 files
/syspool           (syspool           ):819438476 blocks 819438476 files
/var/cores         (syspool/cores     ): 2097090 blocks  2097090 files
root@myhost:~#
```

Comment: If you have command-line access to a shell, post the output from `df`.  I'm guessing there's a good chance one of your disk partitions needed for the OS may have filled up.  It's just a guess, but it's really easy to check.

Answer (score 4):

1) Disconnect all writers and try to reboot your host, it should fix the issue.

2) Contact Nexenta for support you already paid for. Alternatively you can migrate to FreeBSD and keep all of your ZFS volumes: FreeBSD has much bigger community compared to Nexenta.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restart the GUI services. Just call Nexenta if you don't know how.